# How to connect a desktop java application and an online mysql database and execute query?

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-connection

I am trying to create an desktop application for shop. I can create create desktop app and database individually but I dont know how to connect them and how to execute query from desktop. May be for executing query I should use php but I dont know how. My database have been created in hosting site using cpanel.

Comment: can you show what you have done? what exactly is bothering you?

Comment: Take a peek at JDBC tutorials.  That should be a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of APIs on the server side. First learn about [RESTful APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and build your server accordingly. Decide a PHP framework to do this with ease.

Next design your desktop application in JAVA which has

1. Ability to connect to your APIs ( Give Credentials use [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) or something.)
2. Store data locally and Sync it whenever Internet Connectivity is available ( Resolve conflicts when syncing )

This will need lots of research and efforts. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question. If you are using php to build a desktop application (which appears to be), you must download [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for executing php scripts locally. But I recommend you making a desktop application using java swing or any other popular GUI-based  programming language. Please go through [MySQL using Java's JDBC](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html) tutorial . Also Google as the question has a quite broad scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is Vague But here is a tutorial on creating a Java Connection to a database.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html